# Is Jason Isaacs in John Wick?

Tags: john-wick

Google says he is, IMDB says he isn't. I can't see him. Anyone know for sure? Pre production news said he was joining the cast, so if he's not in the film where did he go? Did he film any scenes or was he cut before photography?

Comment: Lots of actors are mentioned in pre-production but often don't make the final film for various reasons. Scheduling conflicts mostly.

Comment: There is also some small Reddit discussion about this. Allegedly his John Wick character was named "David" . I don't remember if there is a David in the film, but if so, you may be able to figure out whom was recast.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found [this IMDb article](http://www.imdb.com/news/ni56304156/) mentioning "Jason Isaacs joins the cast of John Wick."  At the bottom of the article, it also mentions Isaacs had joined the cast of the Brad Pitt vehicle, Fury (which IMDb's cast listing confirms he was a part of.)

Now, what follows is purely supposition on my part, as I couldn't find any direct articles about it, but I do notice that both [Fury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fury_(2014_film)#Filming) and [John Wick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Wick#Filming) were doing principal filmography between September and December 2013, and in very different parts of the world.

For Fury:

> Principal photography began on September 30, 2013, in the Oxfordshire countryside... Filming was wrapped up on November 15, 2013 in Oxfordshire.

For John Wick:

> On 14 October 2013, shooting began in Mill Neck, New York, with the filming process scheduled to continue in and around New York City and greater New York area... Principal photography was confirmed to have ended on December 20, 2013

So, I suspect that Isaacs had to drop one of the movies due to scheduling conflicts, and evidently he chose to drop *John Wick.*  (Perhaps because *Fury* had already started filming before the other, but again, this is just me putting 2 + 2 together, without a direct reference.)